# UIWebView loadRequest white screen

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, youtube-api

I think I have covered most, if not all the related posts in stackoverflow. Unfortunately I still can;t find my answer.

Basically, my app contains a UIWebview which auto play youtube video by (the YouTube JS API)

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YT_Player" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The function which contains this line of code is being called every x min, where x comes from the database. This is done by

```
[self performSelector:@selector(resetVideo) withObject:self afterDelay:x];
```

The whole function is like this:

```
-(void) resetVideo {
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView stopLoading];
    [webView release];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 200)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    [webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YT_Player" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];    
}
```

Also, in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    //call the javascript in YT_Player.html to set the video code, which comes 
    from the db as well
    // done by using   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:scriptStr
}
```

It always play the youtube video fine when the app starts, it then simply shows as a white screen in the UIWebView area when the next video tries to come up. Besides, it seems to me that this problem only exists in real device (not on simulator).

Some more info:
I defined UIWebView *webView; in .h
I tried implementing methods like

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

But no error was shown.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: After some further investigation the problem might be due to that the onPlayerReady() event is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen some weirdness when you recreate a UIWebView over and over. Rather than do this, how about trying to call the [JavaScript function `loadVideoById()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) instead? To do this from Objective-C, you would call:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:"loadVideoById('kt2n27-pi_s')"];
```

To make embedding the iframe player easier in iOS apps, we recently released a [helper library  that you can install via CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper). Check it out. One of the recommendations we make is to NOT recreate the UIWebView over and over if you can.

Comment: I have created a js function:  
function loadVideo(vid) {
        if(ytPlayer)
            ytPlayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
    }

Comment: Do I replace the loadRequest line with     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"loadVideo('R-5XDJhc7fA')"];
?

Comment: No, you still need to load the HTML file. After loading the HTML file (only once), you need to dispatch JavaScript from there on out to load the next videos.

Comment: Hi there again, sorry for asking so many questions. It's really hard to meet an expert from Google (orz). I did some quick coding and things seem going well. I wanna ask if I follow your logic i.e. created only one webView and load the html file once only, should webViewDidFinishLoad() be only called for one cycle (I don;t use once as I realised it is actually called several times as I think each frame loading will trigger the call)? Or it should really be called for more than a cyle whenever a new video is loaded?

Comment: Why don't you try using the library instead? That way you won't have to worry about many of these implementation details. The library is meant to help solve a lot of common problems.

Comment: Hi, just tried your library by following the instruction on the google developer website. When I tried to build and run the project it return the error saying "@synthesize of weak property is only allowed in arc or gc mode". I then tried to  Select Edit -> Refactor... -> Convert to Objective-C ARC. But the same line (@implementation YTPlayerView) in YTPlayerView.m failed.

Answer (score 0):

You're holding a strong reference to a webView object, then you are removing that object from superView, hence the white screen. Instead of holding a strong reference, you can create the webView object as you need or instead of removing it from superview you can toggle it's hidden & userInteractionEnabled properties.

To do without a strong reference:

```
 - (void)resetVideo {
    for (id_object in self.view.subview) {
        if ([id_object isMemberOfClass: [UIWebView class]]) {
            id_object = nil;
            [id_object removeFromSuperView];
        }
    }

    UIWebView* oWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 20, 300, 200)];


    // .. finish as you have above
}
```